# How to find an element from an element in iOS using appuim

Tags: java, ios, selenium, appium

As shown below, I want to check if there is a UIAStaticText for each of the UIACollectionCell.
Is there anyway to find it?
Thanks[image]

Comment: You can check my implementation here [https://stackoverflow.com/a/61430077/9389274]. Hope it can be helpful for you and you can answer to some questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use methods below where `element` is your cell element.

```
element.findElements(By.className("UIAStaticText"));
element.findElement(By.ByClassName"UIAStaticText");
```

Comment: Error in second method:element.findElement(By.className("UIAStaticText"));