# Python Appium implementing Page Object Model

Tags: python, selenium, appium, python-appium

I'm trying to implement 'By' and 'Keys' with appium just like how I do it on selenium.

On selenium i could do this:

Locators

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

class LoginPageLocators(object):
    HEADING = (By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'h3[class="panel-title"]')
    USERNAME = (By.NAME, 'username')
    PASSWORD = (By.NAME, 'password')
    LOGIN_BTN = (By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'input[value="Login"]')
```

functions

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from base import Page
from locators.locators import *

class LoginPage(Page):

    def __init__(self, context):
        Page.__init__(
            self,
            context)

    def goto_login_page(self, url):
        self.open(url)

    def enter_username(self, username):
        uname = self.find_element(*LoginPageLocators.USERNAME)
        uname.send_keys(username)

    def enter_password(self, password):
        pword = self.find_element(*LoginPageLocators.PASSWORD)
        pword.send_keys(password)

    def click_login(self):
        login = self.find_element(*LoginPageLocators.LOGIN_BTN)
        login.click()

    def verify_dashboard_page(self, page):
        self.verify_page(page)
```

Is there a way to this in appium? there is no module if i do this:

```
 from appium.webdriver.common.by import By
 from appium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
from appium.webdriver.common.mobileby import By
from appium.webdriver.common.mobileby import MobileBy

class FirstPageLocators(object):
    LOCATOR_ONE = (MobileBy.ACCESSIBILITY_ID, 'id')
    LOCATOR_TWO = (MobileBy.XPATH, 'xpath_value')
```

Comment: Update, the MobileBy package was deprecated in favor of AppiumBy. Please use ‘from appium.webdriver.common.appiumby import AppiumBy’ instead of ‘MobileBy’.

Please check: https://appium.github.io/python-client-sphinx/webdriver.common.html#module-webdriver.common.mobileby

Answer (score 2):

I use another way for locators.

I have page_object directory, which contains files for the app pages and general file - base_page. In the Base_page.py I include general action methods for another pages. Example:

```
from appium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as ex_cond
from src.platform import PLATFORM, IS_IOS

class BasePage:

    def __init__(self, driver: webdriver) -> None:
        self._driver = driver

    def get_element(self, locator: str, timeout=10):
        by = get_locator_by_string(locator)
        return WebDriverWait(self._driver, timeout).until(
            ex_cond.visibility_of_element_located(by), ' : '.join(by))

    def get_no_element(self, locator: str, timeout=10):
        by = get_locator_by_string(locator)
        element = WebDriverWait(self._driver, timeout).until(
            ex_cond.invisibility_of_element_located(by), ' : '.join(by))
        if element is None:
            return 'No element found'


    def get_element_text(self, locator: str, timeout=10):
        by = get_locator_by_string(locator)
        element = WebDriverWait(self._driver, timeout).until(
            ex_cond.visibility_of_element_located(by), ' : '.join(by))
        if IS_IOS:
            return element.get_attribute('label')
        else:
            return element.text

    def get_element_and_click(self, locator: str, timeout=10):
        by = get_locator_by_string(locator)
        element = WebDriverWait(self._driver, timeout).until(
            ex_cond.visibility_of_element_located(by), ' : '.join(by))
        return element.click()
```

To find the right way for locators, I created the custom method in the same file - base_page.py. Example:

```
def get_locator_by_string(locator_with_type):
    exploided_locator = locator_with_type.split(':', 1)
    by_type = exploided_locator[0]
    locator = exploided_locator[1]

    if by_type == 'xpath':
        return (MobileBy.XPATH, locator)
    elif by_type == 'css':
        return (MobileBy.CSS_SELECTOR, locator)
    elif by_type == 'id':
        return (MobileBy.ID, locator)
    elif by_type == 'accessibility_id':
        return (MobileBy.ACCESSIBILITY_ID, locator)
    elif by_type == 'android_uiautomator':
        return (MobileBy.ANDROID_UIAUTOMATOR, locator)
    elif by_type == 'ios_uiautomation':
        return (MobileBy.IOS_UIAUTOMATION, locator)
    elif by_type == 'ios_predicate':
        return (MobileBy.IOS_PREDICATE, locator)
    elif by_type == 'class':
        return (MobileBy.CLASS_NAME, locator)
    else:
        raise Exception(f'Cannot get type of locator. Locator 
            {locator_with_type}')
```

Get_locator_by_string doesn't consist all search methods. There is methods I need.

In the locators file I have two ways - for Android and for iOS. Example:

```
import allure
from src.config import BUNDLE_APP
from src.ui.base_page import BasePage, locator_for_platform


class AuthorPage(BasePage):

    _author_title = locator_for_platform({
        'ANDROID': 'id:%s:id/authorName' % BUNDLE_APP,
        'IOS': 'accessibility_id:author_name'
    })

    _subscribe_button = locator_for_platform({
        'ANDROID': 'id:%s:id/subscribeBackground' % BUNDLE_APP,
        'IOS': 'accessibility_id:author_subscribe_button'
    })

    @allure.step('Press subscribe button')
    def press_subscribe_button(self):
        super().get_element_and_click(self._subscribe_button)

    @allure.step('Get subscribe button text')
    def get_subscribe_button_text(self):
        return super().get_element_text(self._subscribe_button_text)

    @allure.step('Get author\'s name text')
    def get_author_name_text(self):
        return super().get_element_text(self._author_title)
```

To choose correct locators for platform I use methods for platform's checking. Example:

```
def locator_for_platform(selectors):
    return selectors.get(PLATFORM, 'Undefined Selector')
```

To check current platform this file:

```
import os
from appium import webdriver
from src import config


def get_env(key, default=None):
    return os.environ.get(key=key, default=default)


def get():
    if IS_ANDROID:
        return webdriver.Remote(
            command_executor=config.APPIUM_HOST,
            desired_capabilities=config.DESIRED_CAPS_ANDROID_RESET
        )
    else:
        return webdriver.Remote(
            command_executor=config.APPIUM_HOST,
            desired_capabilities=config.DESIRED_CAPS_ANDROID_RESET
        )


PLATFORM = get_env('PLATFORM', 'IOS')

IS_ANDROID = PLATFORM == 'ANDROID'
IS_IOS = PLATFORM == 'IOS'
```

And the last file for setup current platform for test:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

export PLATFORM=IOS
export PLATFORM=ANDROID
```

APPIUM_HOST and DESIRED_CAPS_ANDROID_RESET / DESIRED_CAPS_ANDROID_RESET in other file. Example:

```
APPIUM_HOST = 'http://localhost:4445/wd/hub'

DESIRED_CAPS_IOS = {
    'platformName': 'iOS',
    'platformVersion': '13.3',
    'deviceName': 'iPhone 8',
    'automationNam': 'XCUITest',
    'app': MY_APP_IOS
}

DESIRED_CAPS_ANDROID_RESET = {
    'platformName': 'Android',
    'platformVersion': '10',
    'automationName': 'uiautomator2',
    'deviceName': DEVICES['Pixel Emulator (10.0)'],
    'app': MY_APP_ANDROID,
    'unicodeKeyboard': 'true',
    'resetKeyboard': 'true',
    'disableWindowAnimation': 'true',
    'autoWebviewTimeout': '2000',
    'clearDeviceLogsOnStart': 'true'
}
```

DEVICES and MY_APP_ANDROID is another dictionaries.

I hope my experience will be helpful for you.